# Time Series acf, pacf and model_fit question

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

Currently trying to plot acf and pacf but for some reason the x-axis of pacf's in date instead of lag.
Same with the model_fit. Want the x-axis to be in date but now it's in lag.
Just wondering how I could fix these.

```
plot_acf(df['y'])
plot_pacf(df['y'])
```

[ACF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFAgR.png)
[PACF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7r8d.png)

```
model = ARIMA(df['y'].values, order=(0,1,2))
model_fit = model.fit(trend='nc', full_output=True, disp=True)
```

[model_fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGEaI.png)

Comment: For the `model_fit`: since you are passing a numpy array when instantiating the model (i.e. `df["y"].values`), you lose the time index; so try passing `df["y"]` directly there. For the `PACF` case: values also seem to blow up. Can you pass `method="ywmle"` to `plot_pacf` function and see if that helps?

Comment: Hey Mustafa. Wasn't able to fix PACF but the other one worked. Thank you so much for your help! It really gave me a headache for a few days until you saved me ;)